# Dev, Staging, Production in single server using docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment

let's say I have a project. I want to make this project with different environments (dev, stag, prod) using Docker. So I will have three project containers with different environments. I have tried `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up -d --build` but when I run another environment, it just only replaces the container.
how to achieve this? note: each `docker-compose.{env}.yml` have `.env.{env_name}` file self.

Comment: do you consider about kubernetes, such as minikube on single server. With its [namespaces](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/), you can run isolate environments easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compose has the notion of a [project name](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name).  This is used to identify all of the Docker resources that belong to a specific Compose setup.  It defaults to the basename of the current directory; in your setup, this means all three environments have the same project name and their containers will replace each other's.

You can use the [`docker-compose -p`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/#use--p-to-specify-a-project-name) option to override the project name for a single `docker-compose` invocation.  Like the `-f` options you have, you need to provide this option on *every* Compose invocation (or set the [`$COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name) environment variable).

```bash
# Run the same images in all environments
# (requires a fixed `image:` name for each thing that is `build:`ed)
docker-compose build

# Start the three environments
docker-compose \
  -p dev                    \  # alternate project name
  -f docker-compose.yml     \  # base Compose file
  -f docker-compose.dev.yml \  # per-environment overrides
  up -d

docker-compose -p staging -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.staging.yaml up -d
docker-compose -p prod -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yaml up -d
```